# react-hooks: skip first run in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How I can skip first run in `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const first = // ???
  if (first) {
    // skip
  } else {
    // run main code
  }
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The [`useRef` hook can be used to store any mutable value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables), so you could store a boolean indicating if it's the first time the effect is being run.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function MyComponent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const isFirstRun = useRef(true);
  useEffect (() => {
    if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;
      return;
    }

    console.log("Effect was run");
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Clicked {count} times</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Do you see any benefits in using useRef vs useState in this case?

Comment: @estus Using e.g. `const [isFirstRun, setFirstRun] = useState(true);` and using `setFirstRun` the first time the effect is run would cause a re-render, which might not be what you want.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks for sharing. This actually was the problem with my own implementation I noticed.

Comment: Why not simply `let isFirstRun = true;` ?

Comment: @NicolasZozol A regular boolean would not be persisted between renders. You need a ref for that.

Comment: I've seen that. In fact you could use let isFirstRun={value:true} *outside* the function and change `isFirstRun.value=false`. That's not more simple :)

Comment: I had the same question: what would be the downside of declaring the variable outside of the function and setting its value inside of the function? i.e. `let isFirstRun; ... function MyComponent() { useEffect(() => { isFirstRun = false; }) ... }`

Comment: A variable that is declared outside the function is shared by ALL instances of the component.

Comment: **Note**: If you are using multiple useEffects that check for isFirstRun, make sure only the last one (on bottom) is setting isFirstRun to false. React goes through useEffects in order!

Comment: Note: The example code should be as follows

if (isFirstRun.current === true) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;
      return;
    }

since 'isFirstRun.current' is not undefined or null, you need an explicit comparison.