# Converting componentWillReceiveProps function to react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hey all given a basic react component that has `componentWillReceiveProps`. I want to convert this to use react hooks. Now I've looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843675/componentwillreceiveprops-componentdidupdate-for-react-hook) and whilst the answer is straightforward I feel as though I'm miss-understanding something. For example:

```
export class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('HELLO WORLD') // Note this isn't called on initial render
    if (nextProps.match.params.id != this.props.match.params.id) {
      console.log('testing....')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Cool</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that from the above example that we won't get into the if statement unless the nextProps hasn't changed. Now converting the above to function component is like this:

```
export const Example = ({ ...props }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('TESTING')
  }, [props.match.params.id])

  return (
    <div>Cool</div>
  )
}
```

I've also prepared a short recording gif of what I'm seeing. https://recordit.co/hPuwGey6WM

Comment: To add dependencies, you'll need to use arrays. `useEffect(function(0 {}, [props.match.params.id]);` That being said, I think it will always run on the first render

Comment: @SerShubham - sorry you're right even with the array syntax I'm seeing the same thing. You'll see this in the recording.

Comment: `useEffect` always runs on first mount

Comment: right.. so how do I _correctly_ simulate the behaviour of: `componentWillReceiveProps`. Because this doesn't run on first mount.

Comment: @Jagrati - i know that if you don't want an effect to run on first mount you have to pass in an empty array to useEffect. But that would mean I would not be observing any properties.

Comment: Basically this is what I think I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351517/react-hooks-skip-first-run-in-useeffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `useEffect` is designed to run on the first render and everytime it's dependencies change.

To avoid running on the first render, you will have to write your own little custom hook.

```
const useComponentWillReceiveProps = (callback, dependencies) => {
  const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
     if(firstRender) {
        setFirstRender(false);
        return;
     }
     callback();
  }, dependencies);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use refs to avoid the initial re-render like:

```
const useComponentWillReceiveProps = (callback, dependencies) => {
   const firstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
     if(firstRender.current) {
        firstRender.current = false;
        return;
     }
     callback();
  }, dependencies);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` always runs after first render. If you don't want to run `useEffect` on first render , you can use it in combination with `useRef`

```
const Example = ({ ...props }) => {
  const initialRender = useRef(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialRender.current) {
      initialRender.current = false;
    } else {
      // write code here
      console.log("TESTING");
    }
  }, [props.match.params.id]);

  return <div>Cool</div>;
};
```